# Converting audio (music) to notes

Tags: audio, conversion

I have an idea for a program I wish to write, but it requires a way to convert musical audio (single guitar, at first approximation) to notes (e.g., OCR/speech-recognition for music).

Google found *IntelliScore*, but although it advertises more power that I need (several instruments), it is proprietary, and I’m looking for something that is free and GPL-compatible.

Are there any free/GPL programs or libraries that can do this?

Comment: See also [Convert OGG (And other formats) to MIDI? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509569/convert-ogg-and-other-formats-to-midi "Convert OGG (And other formats) to MIDI? - Ask Ubuntu")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s [*Notey*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/noteyrecorder/?source=directory). It can detect notes and transcribe them on screen. It’s GPL, so you should be able to extract and adapt the detection/conversion routines.

[image]

Another options is [*music scribe kit*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/musicscribekit/?source=directory) which:

> Is a toolkit for transcribing a music audio file to common music notation. This is done by manually annotating a spectrogram or something similar and converting it to a MIDI file and to a abc music notation file.

The proprietary program Transcribe! has an [extensive list](http://www.seventhstring.com/resources/transcription.html) of other music-transcription tools, including some that are open-source. You can also check [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/?q=music) for other open-source music-transcription programs.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are Windows specific. I can look algorithms, still. WIll examine list too. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, most of the programs are for Windows, but you can indeed copy the detection/conversion functions of the open-source ones. Good luck.

Comment: Source code is no longer available. https://sourceforge.net/projects/noteyrecorder/ does not provide source code or history, links to https://sites.google.com/site/noteysoftware/Code which refers to http://notey.zxq.net/index.html which does not exist.

Comment: CAUTION: this app does not work in Windows 10 !
(Using microphone fails, playing sample files does not work, running in Compatibility Mode does not help)...  :(

Answer (score 1):

Google recommended `waon`.

Originally on http://waon.sourceforge.net/ I had it compile on Xubuntu 18.04, including gtk-based gui.

## What is waon

> WaoN is a Wave-to-Notes transcriber, that is, the inverse of timidity
>   by Tuukka Toivonen (and its descendants timidity++).
>   (...) My original
>   intention is to pick up voicing of harmony from sound of my favorite
>   pianists. (...)
>
> Currently, WaoN contains three programs:
>
> ```
> waon: transcriber (wav-to-mid converter)
> pv: phase vocoder for time-streching and pitch-shifting
> gwaon: GUI for waon and pv
> ```
>
> WaoN is released under the GNU General Public License.

## Where to find source code

CVS is dated and sourceforge is phasing out. I converted the CVS-based history to git and re-hosted it on https://github.com/fidergo-stephane-gourichon/waon .

## Any options?

Here the summary of options the excutable provides.

```
 ./waon --help

WaoN - a Wave-to-Notes transcriber, Version 0.10

Copyright (C) 1998-2007 Kengo Ichiki <kichiki@users.sourceforge.net>
Web: http://waon.sourceforge.net/

WaoN is a Wave-to-Notes transcriber,
that is, a converter from sound file to midi file.

Usage: ./waon [option ...]

Options:
  -h --help print this help.
  -v, --version print version information.
OPTIONS FOR FILES
  -i --input    input wav file (default: stdin)
  -o --output   output mid file (default: 'output.mid')
    options -i and -o have argument '-' as stdin/stdout
  -p --patch    patch file (default: no patch)
FFT OPTIONS
  -n        sampling number from WAV in 1 step (default: 2048)
  -w --window   0 no window
        1 parzen window
        2 welch window
        3 hanning window (default)
        4 hamming window
        5 blackman window
        6 steeper 30-dB/octave rolloff window
READING WAV OPTIONS
  -s --shift    shift number from WAV in 1 step
        (default: 1/4 of the value in -n option)
PHASE-VOCODER OPTIONS
  -nophase  don't use phase diff to improve freq estimation.
        (default: use the correction)
NOTE SELECTION OPTIONS
  -c --cutoff   log10 of cut-off ratio to scale velocity of note
        (default: -5.0)
  -r --relative log10 of cut-off ratio relative to the average.
        (default: no relative cutoff
        = absolute cutoff with the value in -c option)
  -k --peak peak threshold for note-on, which ranges [0,127]
        (default: 128 = no peak-search = search only first on-event)
  -t --top  top note [midi #] (default: 103 = G7)
  -b --bottom   bottom note [midi #] (default: 28 = E1)
    Here middle C (261 Hz) = C4 = midi 60. Midi # ranges [0,127].
  -a --adjust   adjust-pitch param, which is suggested by WaoN after analysis.
        unit is half-note, that is, +1 is half-note up,
        and -0.5 is quater-note down. (default: 0)
DRUM-REMOVAL OPTIONS
  -psub-n   number of averaging bins in one side.
        that is, for n, (i-n,...,i,...,i+n) are averaged
        (default: 0)
  -psub-f   factor to the average, where the power is modified as
        p[i] = (sqrt(p[i]) - f * sqrt(ave[i]))^2
        (default: 0.0)
OCTAVE-REMOVAL OPTIONS
  -oct  factor to the octave removal, where the power is modified as
        p[i] = (sqrt(p[i]) - f * sqrt(oct[i]))^2
        (default: 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide you with a software solution, but can address the underlying issue: which is that of recognizing the "natural" tones in an arbitrary source. The missing piece in the puzzle is that of making effective use of the phase part of a spectrogram to *reassign* the frequencies in the spectrum to their more natural positions (the "instantaneous frequencies" in the spectrum). The result is a greater concentration of the spectrum onto chirp lines. A similar consideration also applies to scalograms - which differ from spectrograms in that they are on a logarithmic scale for frequency, rather than on a linear scale.

The Loris package is one package that I'm aware of that provides a set of routines include those for estimating instantaneous frequencies.

Since you're writing your own software you may try to directly implement methods for reassignment either for spectrograms or scalograms and use that as the intermediate step in your analysis. One possibility may be to experiment with the formulae I provide in the description part of this demonstration video. There is a method, tuned specifically for wavelet-based scalograms, called "synchrosqueezing" that does the scalaographic analogue of reassignment.

The formulae I list are much simpler and carry out a similar analysis more directly and have the added advantage that the individual components in the scalogram are also bona fide sound components (since the phase is there, too) so that the total sound would actually be the sum of the component sounds. In other words, the "inverse" transform (from scalogram to sound) is just simple addition.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OugT7uGGtNg

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.